# Как составить регулярное выражение (цифра от 1 до 4, нельзя повторять одинаковые цифры, можно использовать только запятые)?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярное выражение для проверки, что строка отвечает следующим требованиям:

1. Цифры от 1-4
2. Нельзя повторять одинаковые цифры
3. Можно использовать только запятые

Пока получилось что-то типа этого, но оно позволяет использовать цифры повторно

`^[1-4]{0,1}?( *, *[0-9]{0,1})*$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте

```js
/^(?!.*(\d).*\1)[1-4](?:,[1-4])*$/
```

Если вокруг запятых разрешены пробелы:

```js
/^(?!.*(\d).*\1)[1-4](?: *, *[1-4])*$/
/^(?!.*(\d).*\1)[1-4](?:\s*,\s*[1-4])*$/
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/PNN5Nz/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*(\d).*\1)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции (начала строки) есть какой-то текст (без символов перевода строки), после которого есть цифра, которая потом повторяется
- `[1-4]` - цифра от 1 до 4
- `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

  - `\s*,\s*` - запятая с необязательными пробельными символами вокруг
  - `[1-4]` - цифра от 1 до 4
- `)*` - конец незахватывающей подмаски, 0 и более повторов
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Я так понимаю оба варианта допускают пробелы, а как сделать, чтобы пробелы были запрещены?

Comment: @ИванЕфремов  Удалите `\s*` / `<пробел>*`